# How to insert values into an array in Assembly 80386?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to replace the empty 5 integer array, xarr with numbers 1-5. The code compiles and I believe it is correct except for this last part. My output is now 12345, which is what I need. However, I am only supposed to use the print function once at the end, and the output 12345 should be vertical (one at a time), not horizontal.

```
.globl _asm_main


.section .data, ""

.section .bss, ""
xarr: .fill 5, 4, 0

.section .text, ""
_asm_main:
    enter   $0, $0      # set up stack frame
    pusha           # save registers

    movl $1, %edi
    movl %edi, xarr(, %edi, 4)
    movl xarr(, %edi, 4), %eax
    call print_int
    incl %edi
    movl %edi, xarr(, %edi, 4)
    movl xarr(, %edi, 4), %eax
    call print_int
    incl %edi
    movl %edi, xarr(, %edi, 4)
    movl xarr(, %edi, 4), %eax
    call print_int
    incl %edi
    movl %edi, xarr(, %edi, 4)
    movl xarr(, %edi, 4), %eax
    call print_int
    incl %edi
    movl %edi, xarr(, %edi, 4)
    movl xarr(, %edi, 4), %eax
    call print_int

    popa            # restore registers
    movl    $0, %eax    # return program status in eax
    leave           # restore stack frame
    ret
```

Comment: Please don't say sorry about the formatting, rather fix it. Select all code and click the {} button.

Comment: Thank you for the trivial help.

Comment: _8088_? This looks like (at least) 80386. Anyway, I don't see you writing to `xarr` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it is likely 80386. I have coded in Assembly for a week. If I'm understanding what you are saying, that is is my question exactly. As the .bss section is uninitialized, I have to find a way to give integer values,1-5, to the 5 elements in xarr. And I must leave the array in the .bss section...

Comment: Since this code doesn’t do what you think it does, please comment every `mov` line so that we know what you think. And check whether these comments would make sense.

Comment: Well, you're reading from `xarr` in one place. Writing would be the opposite of reading.

Comment: @RolandIllig the comments (actually helped me) are in...tell me what you think.

Comment: @Michael that's true...What would recommend I do then?

Answer (score 0):

According to the very last `mov` instruction, it should be:

```
movl from_where, to_where
```

This is because one cannot move from `%eax` to zero.

Therefore the order of your operands to the other `mov`s is wrong.

```
movl xarr(, %edi, 4), %eax     # read from the array
movl %edi, xarr(, %edi, 4)     # write into the array; note the %edi instead of the %eax
```

And pay attention to what each register contains at each point. You don’t seem to initialize `%eax` but write its value into the array.

You should probably write this program in C first, test it carefully, let the compiler translate it to assembler and then look at the generated code.

By the way, in assembler languages the comments are usually written so that they all start in the same column.

Comment: I'm confused, the zero is being moved _into_ the %eax register. The skeleton of this code was provided to us beforehand, and we were instructed we should only have to edit the .text section between the pusha and popa. Even if, I have printed the result prior to the final mov instruction.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Our teacher did mention programming it in C/C++ and then extracting the object file is possible, but we have really only had exposure to C#. Can you please read my updated description and advise me further? And what should I initialize eax to?